# WCF Routing and use of single connection

Tags: wcf, wcf-routing

I am playing with WCF Routing. It works fine from the start ... but there is an issue I couldn't pass. In my playground I have routing service and 4 other WCF services implementing 2 different contracts. As I said it works fine ... but when accessing both contracts from client side, from single thread, I have to make 2 different connections. To access contracts ChannelFactory<> is used. I tried to get through WCF channel stack to get idea how to implement own binding/channel but failed to achieve the goal of single connection.

There is an option to generate interface as a sum of both interfaces, but this solution is supposed to work in the environment of many (30-40) independent contracts. What complicates and prevents me from applying this simple solution is the fact, that according to the "loose coupling" rule all those 30-40 independent contracts live independently.

Is there a way to construct channel stack in the way that allows us to route many contracts through single WCF Routing service and use single connection (connection pool/connection pool per thread) for accessing them from the client side. ?

Kind regards

Leszek

Answer (score 0):

There is no "toolkit" way of doing this but you could combine the two contract on the client making sure that the actions are preserved and then route by action in the routing service to the correct downstream service

Comment: That I tried already. For tests only I've made an interface deriving from my test contracts, with additional ServiceContractAttribute it works smoothly. Problem comes when there are the same methods in two different interfaces, combined together there is problem during channel creation. I solved this setting operation name implicitly. Still what I have to do is combine all 40 interfaces in code or emit such a type in runtime. In both scenarios I am supposed to know all interfaces I will use during communication before anything would happen - and for now this is assumption I can't make

Comment: You can call the method something different on the client side - its the action that determines what goes across the wire

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same without combined contract ? Maybe some kind of custom channel/binding. I looked through channel stack but found nothing to start from

Comment: Well you will still need a single entity on the client to invoke (unless I have misunderstood your intent) so I can't see any way but to combine the contracts if you want to use a typed proxy (rather than one that uses the Message type as a parameter)